# Django find duplicates in two tables

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a database of public figures and their positions. I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField()
    appointments = models.ManyToManyField('Appointment', through='PersonsNAppointments')

class Appointment(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField()
    persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='PersonsNAppointments')
```

Names are not unique. So in situation when I have John Donne(id_1) and John Donne(id_2) and "John Donne"  got appointed they both would get this appointment. I want to create an admin panel where only people with same names and same appointments are shown so the admin could handle these duplicates manually. I need help with writing get_queryset.

So far I've figured out how to get duplicated names

```
dup_names = Persons.objects.values('full_name')\
                .annotate(name_count=Count('id'))\
                .filter(name_count__gt=1).values('full_name')

dup_objects = Persons.objects.filter(full_name__in=dupes_names)
```

How to get only those persons who share same appointments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in one query:

```
class MyDoublePersonsModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Person
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        quesryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return queryset.annotate(name_count=Count('appointments__persons__id').filter(appointments__persons__name = F('name'), name_count__gt = 1)
```

1. `annotate` adds count by person hwo get appointment.
2. `filter` get only annotated person with duplicated names.
3. `filter` get only appointments where more than one person with duplicated name.

Comment: thanks! your answer made me learn a lot about django;)